# Sending the next element of the clicked button into jQuery UI dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

After trying to animate an element, when clicking on a button using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#oone, #otwo, #othree, #ofour, #ofive, #osix, #oseven, #oeight, #onine, #oten, #otwelve, #otwenty, #othirteen, #ofourteen, #ofifteen, #osixteen, #loone, #lotwo, #lothree, #lofour, #lofive, #losix, #loseven, #loeight, #lonine, #laaten, #lotwelve, #lotwenty, #lothirteen, #lofourteen, #lofifteen, #losixteen").click(function()
    {
    // $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    // var divs = $("#div_one, #div_two, #div_three, #div_four, #div_five, #div_six, #div_seven, #div_eight, #div_nine, #dive_ten, #div_eleven, #div_twelve, #div_thirteen, #div_fourteen, #div_fifteen, #div_sixteen, #div_lone, #div_ltwo, #div_lthree, #div_lfour, #div_lfive, #div_lsix, #div_lseven, #div_leight, #div_lnine, #dive_lten, #div_leleven, #div_ltwelve, #div_lthirteen, #div_lfourteen, #div_lfifteen, #div_lsixteen");
    // $(divs).siblings().slideToggle();

      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
   });
});
```

I've got some animation unwanted result. So I decided, instead of animating the next element of the clicked button, why I don't send the result into dialog bix using `jQuery UI` plugin. So I tried the following:

```
<script src="../include/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../include/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../include/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#oone, #otwo, #othree, #ofour, #ofive, #osix, #oseven, #oeight, #onine, #oten, #otwelve, #otwenty, #othirteen, #ofourteen, #ofifteen, #osixteen, #loone, #lotwo, #lothree, #lofour, #lofive, #losix, #loseven, #loeight, #lonine, #laaten, #lotwelve, #lotwenty, #lothirteen, #lofourteen, #lofifteen, #losixteen").click(function() {

    $(this).next().dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      hide: "puff",
      show: "slide",
      width: 800,
      modal: true
    });
    //$(this).dialog("open");
  });
});
```

And here is the html code for only the first 2 buttons, because the cod is too long:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="oone" name="one" alt="button" />
  <div id="div_one" class="collapse">3rd Molar:
    <?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?>
  </div>
  <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="otwo" name="two" alt="button" />
  <div id="div_two" class="collapse">
    <?php echo $resTeeth['two'] ?>
  </div>
```

So I had this error:

```
jquery-1.12.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
```

How to fix this error, and is it possible to send the `next()` div element into `dialog` box using `jQuery UI`, or should I specify id for each div, and create a dialog script for each one of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, you're creating the dialog from the next div, but you're trying to open the dialog on the CURRENT div.
You can fix this pretty easy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#oone, #otwo, #othree, #ofour, #ofive, #osix, #oseven, #oeight, #onine, #oten, #otwelve, #otwenty, #othirteen, #ofourteen, #ofifteen, #osixteen, #loone, #lotwo, #lothree, #lofour, #lofive, #losix, #loseven, #loeight, #lonine, #laaten, #lotwelve, #lotwenty, #lothirteen, #lofourteen, #lofifteen, #losixteen").click(function() {
        var dialog = $(this).next();
        dialog.dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          hide: "puff",
          show: "slide",
          width: 800,
          modal: true
        });
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the assumption you want the dialog to contain the contents of the next (following) div.

This would do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dialog = '<div class="mydialog" title="Basic dialog"><p class="dialogcontent">me</p></div>';
  var newDiv = $(dialog);
  newDiv.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    hide: "puff",
    show: "slide",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $(".form-group").on('click', ".img1", function() {
  var me = $(this);
    newDiv.find('.dialogcontent').html(me.next('.collapse').html())
    newDiv.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Example in action: https://jsfiddle.net/89pyhsuj/